# Want to get the previous input from the button where I click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the previous input `id` from the button (point of view).
With the needs of my website, there will be at least 8 inputs like this and buttons of course.

So in order to facilite the task and avoid writing one function by input, I think this is way better to get the id of the 'previous' input from the button where I click.

I've browsed StackOverflow, but found nothing interesting in my case.

[image: qsd]

So here is the HTML code :

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" ><i class="fas fa-link"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="first_map_link" class="form-control" id="first_map_link" placeholder="Lien première map...">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-get-infos"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried with that : Undefined

```
$('.btn-get-infos').closest('input').attr('id')
```

Same with siblings. jQuery solution is prefered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` goes up the DOM looking for parent elements, while the `input` you want to find is a child of a sibling to a parent of the button you click on. With that in mind you'll need a combination of `closest()`, `prev()` and `find()`, like this:

```
var id = $('.btn-get-infos').closest('.row').prev('.col-sm-3').find('input').prop('id')
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Now, I need to pass it to an other function, do I need to append before a '#' to get the value of this ID ?

Comment: If you want to get the value of the input then you already have a reference to it, just do `.find('input').val()` instead

Comment: Perfect, thanks you so much, I will try, and will post if it's working :)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to walk up and down the DOM properly to find reference.  Something like this:

```
$('.btn-get-infos').prev().find('input').attr('id');
```

Or if you're firing a click event, it can use the `this` keyword:

```
$this = $(this); //ref to the button clicked
$this.prev().('input').attr('id');
```

Give that a go and let us know if it works, dude.  `attr()` i think was deprecated a while back, so new practise is to use `prop()`.

Edit:  I realise now that prev() only looks through previous `siblings` - ignore me :)

Comment: There is no `prev()` element from the button, and you appear to have a syntax error; `.('input')`

Comment: Whoops.  Copy / paste laziness there.  And thanks for making me look up the jquery docs for `prev()`